# How to delete first row of inline-block divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of inline-block divs on my web page,

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="text">Text 4</div>
      <div class="text">Text 5</div>
      <div class="text">Text 6</div>
      <div class="text">Text 7</div>
</div>
```

and they wrap around like this:

[image]

I want to be able to delete the first row of them, that is in this case 1-5. But if I scale this to where only 1-3 are in the first row, I would only like to delete those. (you get it)

I don't have any clue what kind of javascript can be applied for this particular use case, but for simplicity, heres the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex2nqdgy/3/). I would rather not use JQuery.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: The idea is to get the X position of the first item and to fins all divs with the same X position. This is the first row.

Comment: Also must they be deleted or can they just be hidden? When resized it is easier to modify display

Comment: @Azu If we are talking about left-to-right, then you must mean "Y-position", not X. But yes, then your idea holds true.

Comment: @Oskar, right, I meant Y position, thank you.

Comment: "I want to be able to delete ..." Do you mean on will, as in when a button is pressed? If not, do you mean on page load, once the parent element is displayed, or perhaps _always?_ If always, then wouldn't that be equal to deleting all rows? Since upon deleting one, the next row would be the now-first row. Please clarify.

Answer (score -2):

If the width of each item is the same, you can get the width of container, divide by the width of each item (to determine the number of items in each row), then delete that many items from the start.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.text');
const itemWidth = item.offsetWidth + 2 * parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue("margin"));
const containerWidth = document.querySelector('.container').offsetWidth;
const itemsInFirstRow = Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth);

document.querySelectorAll('.text').forEach((e,i) => {
  if(i < itemsInFirstRow) e.remove()
})
```

```css
.text {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="text">Text 1</div>
      <div class="text">Text 2</div>
      <div class="text">Text 3</div>
      <div class="text">Text 4</div>
      <div class="text">Text 5</div>
      <div class="text">Text 6</div>
      <div class="text">Text 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about window resize?